# Ajax get call not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, backbone.js

i have following kind of url

```
  http://11.11.11.11/url/index.php?data={method:method_name,params:{param1:value,param2:value,}}
```

and i want to pass data from backbone view to ajax class which has following kind of structure

```
define(['jquery', 'backbone'],
function($, Backbone) {
    var ajax = {
        getDataCall: function(url, data, successCallBack, failureCallBack) {
            var that = this;
            //console.log(method);
            //console.log(successCallBack);
            that.showLoading();
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                method: 'get',
                data: data,
                // contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data) {
                    that.hideLoading();
                    //alert("success ajax");
                    successCallBack(data);
                },
                fail: function(data) {
                    that.hideLoading();
                    failureCallBack(data);
                }
            });
        },
        showLoading: function() {
            $.blockUI();
            //$.blockUI({ message: '<img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" />' })
        },
        hideLoading: function() {
            $.unblockUI();
        }
    };
    return ajax;
});
```

and from backbone view i am calling

```
var dataToSend={"method":"method","params":{"param2":"param2"}}  

ajax.getDataCall("http://11.11.11.11/url/index.php?",dataToSend,successCallBack,failureCallback)
```

but it is not turning into correct url. What is wrong in this code?

Comment: means are you hitting the url and parameters are going wrong or you are not even able to call the url?

Comment: when i call url using this way proper url(http://11.11.11.11/url/index.php?data={method:method_name,params:{param1:value,param2:value,}}) is not getting generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting setup.  I never really seen JSON format in an URL before.  BUT, basically jQuery takes a object literal in the data attribute and serializes it on the default contentType.

Anyway, the solution is you need to 1) stringify the object, 2) take away the quotes, and 3) put "data=" as you have placed there:

```
var dataToSend={"method":"method","params":{"param2":"param2"}};
dataToSend = 'data=' + JSON.stringify( dataToSend ).replace(/\"/g, '');

ajax.getDataCall("http://11.11.11.11/url/index.php?",dataToSend,successCallBack,failureCallback)
```

Comment: url is correct bt still method is not valid is coming in response eventhough both urls are same

Comment: maybe you can provide more of what you're trying to accomplish or how you're using this url structure?

Comment: i want quotes in url http://11.11.11.11/url/index.php?data={"method":"method_name","params":{"param1":"value","param2":"value"}} how to do that

Comment: Then take out the "replace":  `dataToSend = 'data=' + JSON.stringify( dataToSend );`.  That would result in quotes being replaced by `%22`.  If you need to decode that coming in then you need to use `decodeURI()`